# Edit HTML <a> Tag without href attribute Inside a Contenteditable Div

Tags: css, html, dom

I found when editing a `<a>` tag, the behavior is different when it has attribute href or not.

1. Adding character after `<a>` tag with href (the cursor was inside the `<a>` node), the added char will not be inside the `<a>` tag

   ```html
   <a href="fakelink">tes</a>
   ```

   type 't' it will become

   ```html
   <a href="fakelink">tes</a>"t"
   ```
2. Adding character after  tag without href (the cursor was inside the  node), the added char will be inside the  tag

   ```html
   <a>tes</a>
   ```

   type 't' it will become

   ```html
   <a>test</a>
   ```

why is this?

Is it possible to make a span node behave like first case, I mean when you add character after that span node (the cursor was inside the span node), the new char is outside the span node?

Comment: What? Are you talking about a specific editor?

Comment: it is inside a contenteditable div

Comment: contenteditable is working as expected on div contents not on a tag , either you should move contenteditable = true to anchor tag to work with or without href https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QrGYjN

Comment: @NagaSaiA I found when move the `contenteditable=true` to anchor tag, then adding char after that will be inside the anchor tag no matter with href or not.  but i was expecting that for a span node inside a contenteditable Div, add a char after that the added char goes out side the span. like the <a> with href in the above example in the question. is it possible ?